# How to get a reference to the row number from a julia dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, julia

In Julia, dataframes are output with a sequential row number. I would like to access the row numbers as if it were a ROWID in the dataframe. I need this to calculate a regression.

Right now I do this with trick to add an extra column (x1) to mimic the rowid:

```
data = hcat(data, collect(1:size(data,1)));
glm(Column ~ x1, data, Normal(), IdentityLink())
```

I would like to achieve this directly, without adding an extra x1 column to the table. The x1 column I use now is a workaround. So what I'd like to achieve is to get the first line that adds an extra column. If the x1 column is not added, the glm() function crashes.
So I need to find a direct replacement for the x1 in the glm() function (if that is possible).

Is there a simple way to get to the rowid of the tableframe?

Comment: Not exactly an answer to the question but `data[:x1] = [1:nrow(data)...]` may be more pleasant code

Comment: it's not clear what you mean. You already *can* access the rows in a dataframe by number (e.g. `df = DataFrame(a=[1,2,3], b=[4,5,6]); df[2,1]` )

Comment: Maybe I did not express my question clearly enough. It is not my intend to elegantly add an extra column to my dataframe, but to avoid having to add an extra column. I modified the question, hoping to get a clear question.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from DataFrames v0.22.0 [rownumber(dfr::DataFrameRow)](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/v0.22/lib/functions/#DataFrames.rownumber) returns the row number.

```
julia> data = DataFrame(a=4:6, b=7:9)
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b     
     │ Int64  Int64 
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     4      7
   2 │     5      8
   3 │     6      9

julia> rownumber.(eachrow(data))
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
```

Comment: Is there any way to get this inside of a `transform` without adding the column manually?